# Is it possible to force a linux install to continue?

Tags: linux, rpm, pxe-boot, kickstart, packages

I'm PXE booting a linux distro that I'd like to contain a list of packages. I have these packages listed in a kickstart file for inclusion. Some of these packages won't work with the current distro, and during installation I get "cannot open .rpm". Currently I'm looking to find out which packages are not going to work, but it will only one package that fails at a time, at which point I have to remove the failed package from the ks, attempt to reinstall to get to the next failed package.

I was wondering if there was a way to force the installation to continue after encountering the error so that I might see all the failed packages at once, rather than going through one at a time.

I don't expect the force continue to result in a working OS, just that I might be able to see the packages that cannot be used in one attempt

Comment: Is this question about the Anaconda installer? Which distribution are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just tell anaconda to ignore missing packages

%packages --ignoremissing

you will have to consult the ks anaconda file to see what was actually installed

one more option might be to add a conflicts group to the exclusion
-@Conflicts (Workstation)
to exclude packages which conflict in workstation installation for example.

EDIT
After re-reading your question I am wondering if you are referring to 3rd party packages.
If so, I would suggest a different course - either use a post install script, OR, if you intend to make this the basis of a large scale deployment - take the time to install in a virtual environment (e.g. vbox) and then install all 3rd party packages with a single yum install command. You'll get to see conflicts and bad OS version/ dependency issues interactively, which is much easier to debug IMO than reading a log after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

You can always try to do [32.7. Post-installation Script](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-postinstallconfig.html) and install whatever after you done with your initial install.

Comment: I like it, that might help speed things along